# Selecting element by attributes in data and addClass methods

Tags: jquery

I need obtain elements based on id and class:

```
$('<div/>').data('id', 'xxx').addClass('myclass');
```

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Edit: the element I have written is the example, it has no more attributes. How do I get that element based on that id (xxx) and class?

the problem is in obtaining the element by its id and its class, the elements are created dynamically and I have 2 elements with same id but different class:

```
 $('<div/>').data('id', '111').addClass('myclass_1');
 $('<div/>').data('id', '111').addClass('myclass_2');
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
var div = $('div[data-id="'+xxx+'"][class="myclass_1"]');
```

An example:

```
<html>
    <div id="parentContainer"></div>
    <div id="otherParentContainer"></div>
</html>

<script>
    
    var parent = $('#parentContainer');
    var otherParent = $('#otherParentContainer');

    $('<div/>').data('id', 'parentContainer').addClass('myclass_1').appendTo(parent);
    $('<div/>').data('id', 'parentContainer').addClass('myclass_2').appendTo(parent);
    $('<div/>').data('id', 'parentContainer').addClass('myclass_3').appendTo(parent);
    
    $('<div/>').data('id', 'otherParentContainer').addClass('myclass_1').appendTo(otherParent);
    $('<div/>').data('id', 'otherParentContainer').addClass('myclass_2').appendTo(otherParent);
    
    function obtainSpecificDiv (parentContainerId){
        
        //  i need manipulate the div whith class myclass_2
        var div = $('div[data-id="parentContainerId"][class="myclass_2"]'); // not work
        
    }

</script>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  Can you update the question with a more complete and runnable example which demonstrates what you're trying to do and what isn't working, and explain specifically what the problem is?

Comment: Do you want to select elements by `data` attribute ? eg. `$('[data-id="xxx"]').addClass('myclass');`

Comment: If you need to get an element based on ID and CLASS then use `$('#YOURID.YOURCLASS')`

Comment: Please include the HTML for the 2 elements, then all will becomes clear (hopefully)

Comment: `.data('id', '111')` *sets* the in-memory data value, it does not update the html - you might need `.attr("data-id", "111")` if you're trying to *set* the data-id attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking of `HTML` that's added after the page loads. If, for instance you have the divs:

```
<div data-id="xyz1" class="abc1">First</div>
<div data-id="xyz1" class="abc2">Second</div>
```

Here is how to select the first div:

```
$('[data-id="xyz1"].abc1').....
```

Assuming that while creating this content `.attr('data-id', 'xyz1')` was used. However, if `.data('id', 'xyz1')` was used, then you would select the first div thus:

```
$('.abc1').filter(function() { return $(this).data('id') === 'xyz1'; }).....
```

```js
$(function() { 
    var parent = $('#parentContainer');
    var otherParent = $('#otherParentContainer');

    $('<div/>').data('id', 'parentContainer').addClass('myclass_1').appendTo(parent);
    $('<div/>').data('id', 'parentContainer').addClass('myclass_2').appendTo(parent);
    $('<div/>').data('id', 'parentContainer').addClass('myclass_3').appendTo(parent);
    
    $('<div/>').data('id', 'otherParentContainer').addClass('myclass_1').appendTo(otherParent);
    $('<div/>').data('id', 'otherParentContainer').addClass('myclass_2').appendTo(otherParent);
    
    function obtainSpecificDiv (parentContainerId){
        var div = $('.myclass_2').filter(function() { return $(this).data('id') === parentContainerId; }) 
        console.log( div[0] );
        return div;
    }
    
    obtainSpecificDiv('parentContainer').text('We selected this ......');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parentContainer"></div>
<div id="otherParentContainer"></div>
```

The reason you cannot use an attribute selector, `[data-id="...."]` is because the generated HTML does not have `data` attributes.

```
<div id="parentContainer">
  <div class="myclass_1"></div>
  <div class="myclass_2"></div>
  <div class="myclass_3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's how it works. Thanks so much. That’s very kind of you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what youre looking for, but to give an element a className by ID:

```
$('#yourId').addClass('yourClass');
```

and to give a ID by className:

```
$('.yourClass').attr('id', 'yourId');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div[id=xxx]").addClass('myclass');
```

OR

```
$("#xxx").addClass('myclass');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you select element by data attribute

```
$('div[data-id="111"]')
```

This is how you can select by data attribute and class

```
$('div[data-id="111"].my-class')
```